# How to set up Https on cPanel

Tags: https, cpanel

Hello
I want to set up http**s** on CPanel!
 but I don't know how?

Is there anyone here that can help me?
My cpanel version is cPanel Pro 1.0 (RC1).

Comment: Do you want to access your cPanel over https, or make it so that all or part of your site is accessible over https?

Comment: i done this.
now tell me what settings to be done to open only https version of site, even if user enter xyz.com - it should open https://xyz.com.

Comment: If you search this site you can find the answer to your question, e.g. webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/switch-to-https. I removed your email address from your answer (now a comment) as if someone emails the answer to you then no-one else can find out how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step-by-step instructions**

*make sure you have download the appropriate files for your certificate before beginning*

1. Open the WebHost Manager and click Activate your SSL Certificate in the SSL/TLS menu.

   You will see a screen with three boxes on it. Your issued certificate, RSA private key and certificate bundle must be pasted into boxes 1, 2, and 3, respectively.
2. In the first box, paste in the contents of your issued SSL certificate. If the certificate file is on your server, you may use the Fetch button to copy it from the file.
3. In the second box, paste in your private key which was generated when you created the CSR.
4. In the third box, paste in the certificate bundle (gd_bundle.crt).
   At the top of the page click Do it.